# How to redirect Cisco IOS's show output to HTTP URL?

Tags: cisco, ios

I found there's a `redirect` output modifier of Cisco IOS ( version `12.2(53)SE1` ), and there's http: URI support:

```
#sh version | redirect ?
  flash:  Uniform Resource Locator
  ftp:    Uniform Resource Locator
  http:   Uniform Resource Locator
  https:  Uniform Resource Locator
  nvram:  Uniform Resource Locator
  rcp:    Uniform Resource Locator
  scp:    Uniform Resource Locator
  tftp:   Uniform Resource Locator
```

However, I cannot find any document on cisco.com about the http support. I tried `sh version | redirect http://my_server/` and cannot find any information on `my_server`'s access log.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the full path and file name. Try something like this:

```
MainRouter# show tech | redirect 
http://USER:MYPASSWORD@192.168.1.112//share/tech.htm
```